# How can I edit this "Home" title and remove the white space beneath it?

Tags: office-365, title

I'm working on a SP whose URL ends with xxx/sitepages/Home.aspx in SharePoint for Office 365. There are two things I'm struggling to fix/change.

1. How can I edit the title, changing it from "Home" to "Quality Management" without changing the URL? I only figured out how to change it in the page properties, but it changes the Home.aspx altogether and I end up with a new URL.
2. Also, how can I remove some white space that is appearing beneath the header and before my page main web part starts?
   Please see the attached picture for both items.[image]

Comment: Are you using classic experience pages only?

Comment: Maybe? When I "edit page", I see a setup that differs from other SPs. There's a block for Header, Footer, Left Column, Middle Column, Right Column.

Comment: Are you able to use content editor or script editor web part on these pages? If yes, you can make required changes using custom JS/CSS.

Comment: Yes, I found them - under "media and content", both content editor and script editor.  Only, I've never used these features before so I'll need to learn how. :)